# Combine two dataframes where column values match

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes containing similar columns:

```
  ID  prop1
1 UUU &&&
2 III ***
3 OOO )))
4 PPP %%%
```

and

```
  ID  prop2
1 UUU 1234 
2 WWW 4567
3 III 7890
5 EEE 0123
6 OOO 3456
7 RRR 6789
8 PPP 9012
```

I need to merge these two dataframes where the IDs match, and add the prop2 column to the original.

```
  ID  prop1 prop1
1 UUU &&&   1234
2 III ***   7890
3 OOO )))   3456
4 PPP %%%   9012
```

Ive tried every combination of merge, join, concat, for, iter, etc. It will either fail to merge, lose the index, or straight-up drop the column values.

Comment: When you merge on a level that isn't the index, bringing along the index is nonsensical -- if there is a match which index should you use, the one from `left` or the one from `right`? So rightfully so, pandas just puts an `Int64Index` on the result. If you need to bring the index along, then you'll need to bring it into the columns before the merge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
```

Output:

```
    ID prop1  prop2
0  UUU   &&&   1234
1  III   ***   7890
2  OOO   )))   3456
3  PPP   %%%   9012
```

You can also use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as follows::

```
df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
```

Same result.

The default parameter on `.merge()` no matter using `pd.merge()` or `df.merge()` is `how='inner'`.  So you are already doing an inner join without specifying `how=` parameter.

### More complex scenario:

If you require the more complicated situation to maintain the index of `df1` `1, 2, 3, 4` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`, you can do it by resetting index before merge and then set index on the interim `index` column produced when resetting index:

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='ID').set_index('index')
```

Output:

```
        ID prop1  prop2
index                  
1      UUU   &&&   1234
2      III   ***   7890
3      OOO   )))   3456
4      PPP   %%%   9012
```

Now, the index `1 2 3 4` of original `df1` are kept.

Optionally, if you don't want the axis label `index` appear on top of the row index, you can do a [`rename_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) as follows:

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='ID').set_index('index').rename_axis(index=None)
```

Output:

```
        ID prop1  prop2
1      UUU   &&&   1234
2      III   ***   7890
3      OOO   )))   3456
4      PPP   %%%   9012
```

Comment: Somehow this just returns an empty dataframe

Comment: @cdubbs  You have to reassign to `df1` like: `df1 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='ID').set_index('index').rename_axis(index=None)`   or assign to a new name.

Comment: @cdubbs   I assumed `df1` is the first dataframe and `df2` is the second.  Is that what you name them.  If no, replace df1, df2  with your dataframe names.

Comment: @cdubbs   I tested with creating the test dataframes by: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {1: 'UUU', 2: 'III', 3: 'OOO', 4: 'PPP'},
 'prop1': {1: '&&&', 2: '***', 3: ')))', 4: '%%%'}})`  and `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {1: 'UUU', 2: 'WWW', 3: 'III', 5: 'EEE', 6: 'OOO', 7: 'RRR', 8: 'PPP'},
 'prop2': {1: 1234, 2: 4567, 3: 7890, 5: 123, 6: 3456, 7: 6789, 8: 9012}})`    The test dataframes work fine for me and they should be the same as your sample data.

Comment: Hi @cdubbs  Is it ok now ?  If no, is there same empty dataframe with defining `df1` `df2` with my codes on the comment above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.map` to add the prop2 values to your original dataframe, where the ID column values match.

```
df1['prop2'] = df1['ID'].map(dict(df2[['ID', 'prop2']].to_numpy())
```

Should there be any IDs in your original dataframe that aren't also in the second one (and so don't have a prop2 value to bring across, you can fill those holes by adding `.fillna()` with the value of your choice.

```
df1['prop2'] = df1['ID'].map(dict(df2[['ID', 'prop2']].to_numpy()).fillna(your_fill_value_here)
```